# In table, <br /> tags displaying on the screen rathen than new line

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table, nl2br

I have a `<table>` and inside `<td>` tags inside it where I am displaying the retrieved data from the backend. Before saving my data to database, I used this to convert `\n` and `\r` into `<br />` tags:

```
$data = nl2br($request->data);
$data = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n"), "", $data);
```

---

To retrieve data, I tried directly echo-ing the value - (`{{ }}` is echo for Laravel)

```
<tr> 
  <td>{{ $item->data }}</td>
</tr>
```

However, this is displaying `<br />` tags on the page instead of turning them into new line breaks.

---

Then I tried using this approach, which I believe would work, however, this is also displaying the `&#13;` on the text rather than converting it to new lines.

```
<tr> 
  <td>@if ($item){{ str_replace('<br />', '&#13;', $item->data) }}@endif</td>
</tr>
```

Also tried replacing br tags to `\n` with using `'\n'` and `'\\n'` inside `str_replace()` but no luck

How can I turn `<br />` tags into new lines as usual inside table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the table.

See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data):

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks.

and

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
> ```
>
> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your
>   application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to
>   prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the str_replace() I showed for my another page as I didn't think that would be that easy. That's what made me think that I need to use fancy stuff. Thanks again